# Vertex count changes when exporting mesh as plymesh

Tags: mesh, export, vertices, import

When I create a simple Icosphere mesh in Blender, the statistics tab shows me that it has 42 vertices. I then export this mesh to .ply and then re-import the .ply-file. Now, the statistics tab shows 63 vertices.

What is going on? Why are some vertices being duplicated?
[image]

Comment: Hello ! Have you tried removing double vertices in edit mode ?

Comment: Hey, yes I just tried merging by distance, which brings back the original - correct - vertex count of 42. But what is going on? Why is .ply, an established format, not imported / exported properly?

Comment: He, I can't say. You'd have to ask either the writers of the importer or the exporter feature.

Comment: If you make your comment into an answer I'll mark as accepted, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here for future reference:

exporting the mesh without UV coordinates solves the issue, i.e., export -> untick "UVs" under the geometry tab.